# How to use a python produce as many subplots of arbitrary size as necessary accommodate all data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have a method of a python class that plots a graph using Matplotlib, how can i then use this method within another to produce subplots of an arbitrary size.

For example

The function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot(x,y):
    fig=plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)

x=[3,3,5,4,6,7,8,6]
y=[6,,5,,7,6,5,4,6]
plot(x,y)
```

would produce a graph. If I had say 30 sets of `(x,y)` pairs, how can i use `plot` in a loop while adding to subfigures, to produce as many subfigures as required. I.e. if we want a 4 by 4 subplots then we need 7 subfigure with the remainder only containing 2 graphs.

Comment: yes, it is somehow possible with a little bit of effort. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[armatita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868335/armatita) answer is perfectly fine, and it will always try to arrange for a "square" of subplots (same number of rows and columns where possible).

If you want the subplots to follow a different aspect ratio (i.e. more columns than rows when you have a 16:9 monitor) you can use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math 

def fitPlots(N, aspect=(16,9)):
    width = aspect[0]
    height = aspect[1]
    area = width*height*1.0
    factor = (N/area)**(1/2.0)
    cols = math.floor(width*factor)
    rows = math.floor(height*factor)
    rowFirst = width < height
    while rows*cols < N:
        if rowFirst:
            rows += 1
        else:
            cols += 1
        rowFirst = not(rowFirst)
    return rows, cols

numberofplots = 31
rows,cols = fitPlots(numberofplots)

plt.figure()
for i in range(1,numberofplots+1):
    x = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
    y = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
    ax = plt.subplot(rows,cols,i)
    ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use subplot to achieve this. The following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot(x,y,i,num):
    snum = np.sqrt(num)+1
    ax = plt.subplot(snum,snum,i)
    ax.plot(x,y)

numberofplots = 31
for i in range(1,numberofplots+1):
    x = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
    y = np.random.randint(0,100,10)
    plot(x,y,i,numberofplots)
```

, results in this:

[image: Multiple plots in a grid]